# EF scaffolding base class members

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-4, scaffolding

I have a class representing object A:

```
public class A
{
  [Key]
  private int _ID;
  private string _property;
  public ID {get {return _ID;} set {_ID = value;}}
  public ID {get {return _property;} set {_property = value;}}
}
```

I scaffold this class into DB as table A using EF (add-migration, update-database)

I have another three objects B,C,D with simillary properties, so I create a base class for them. All this object must contain a List of objects of type A so I create reference to A:

```
public class Base_B_C_D
{
  [Key]
  protected int _ID;
  protected string _prop;
  protected List<A> A_List;
  public ID {get {return _ID;} set {_ID = value;}}
  public ID {get {return _prop;} set {_prop = value;}}
}
```

and inherit B,C,D from it:

```
public class B:Base_B_C_D {}
public class C:Base_B_C_D {}
public class D:Base_B_C_D {}
```

When I scaffold B,C,D into DB using EF I don't see any FK in any table and there is no link between A and B,C,D...

The question is: What is a proper way how to scaffold such links?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With only a few models you should use [table-per-type inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx). You should also use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) for your POCOs. They should be used when no additional logic is required in the property accessors.

If `B`, `C` and `D` contain similar properties to `A` they should just inherit from it. If `B`, `C` and `D` must contain a list of object of `A`, this relationship is represented as one-to-many relationship. This is represented in EF using an `ICollection` and it will act as the FK.

Based on your models, you could implement TPT inheritance like this:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

[Table("B")]
public class B : A
{
    // more properties...

    // 1:Many with A
    public ICollection<A> CollectionA { get; set; }
}

[Table("C")]
public class C : A
{
    // more properties...

    // 1:Many with A
    public ICollection<A> CollectionA { get; set; }
}

[Table("D")]
public class D : A
{
    // more properties...

    // 1:Many with A
    public ICollection<A> CollectionA { get; set; }
}
```

In your context class, you only create one DbSet of type base class:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> Person { get; set; }
}
```

The somewhere in your application you create instances of derived classes:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var b = db.A.Create<B>();
    // ... same for C and D
    db.A.Add(b);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This approach is suitable only if B,C and D has exactly the same properties as the BASE_B_C_D, but if they implement more properties (as you wrote) where this properties will be stored since we have only one DbSet with columns for BASE_B_C_D properties?  I know abuot FK that appear in A, when I include List<A> in B or С or D... but what is inheritance for in that case if I must include List<A> in each derived class? The goal is to include List<A> in BASE_B_C_D and   not to re-write it in B or C or D, but just use through inheritance

Comment: When using TPT inheritance we only create on DbSet of type base class. Annotating derived classes with [Table("...")] will create tables for each derived class in the database with columns that will map directly to the properties in the derived classes i.e. this is where the additional properties will be stored. I'm not too sure if FKs can be realised in EF through inheritance in the way you describe - I always create a collection to represent a 'many' FK. Inheritance allows for reuse of code and creates the is-a relationship between classes.